# Problem with custom colors for both lines and markers with `plot_ly`

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

Let's assume that I want to use custom colors for a line+marker plotly plot.
It is quite straighforward to use the `colors` and `color` arguments of `plot_ly()` but as soon as I want to modify the markers themselves (using the `marker` argument) I encounter difficulties and didn't find help to solve this specific issue on the net.
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
# Underlying data
tmp <- mpg %>%
  group_by(class,manufacturer) %>%
  summarise(models=n())

# Works as expected
tmp %>% 
  plot_ly(x=~manufacturer, 
          y=~models, 
          group=~class,
          type="scatter",
          color=~class, 
          colors = scales::hue_pal()(length(n_distinct(tmp$class))), #ggplot colors
          mode="lines+markers")

# Issue with markers > idea behind is to have a white center and a marker line with the same color as the line itself
tmp %>% 
  plot_ly(x=~manufacturer, 
          y=~models, 
          group=~class,
          type="scatter",
          color=~class, 
          colors = scales::hue_pal()(n_distinct(tmp$class)),
          marker = list(color = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
                        line = list(color = scales::hue_pal()(n_distinct(tmp$class)))),
          mode="lines+markers")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may seem a little strange, but the beautifully simple solution in your case is to drop:

```
line = list(color = scales::hue_pal()(n_distinct(tmp$class))))
```

and only inlcude:

```
line = list(width = 3)
```

Here's your plot now:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
# Underlying data
tmp <- mpg %>%
  group_by(class,manufacturer) %>%
  summarise(models=n())


# Issue with markers > idea behind is to have a white center and a marker line with the same color as the line itself
tmp %>% 
  plot_ly(x=~manufacturer, 
          y=~models, 
          group=~class,
          type="scatter",
          color=~class, 
          colors = scales::hue_pal()(n_distinct(tmp$class)),
          marker = list(color = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
                        line = list(width = 3)),
          mode="lines+markers")
tmp
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer. What if I want to use another color than the one of the curve then? Let's say black? i.e. how shall I customize the marker line color?
Edit > I think `width = 2` by default ;-)

Comment: @yahman269 `line = list(color='black', width = 3))` will set all marker lines to black. Id you'd like more details, please consider raising a new question. Just reference this question and go from there.

Comment: My question is related to the initial topic, but was not asked correctly: here the trick is to NOT provide colors argument for `line`, OK, but what if you want custom colors?